# Strange behavior of "Run in terminal", it kills processes

Tags: bash, shell, service, terminal, gnome

I wrote a shell script that runs a service. I open the terminal, I run the script that runs the service and, after the script ends, I close the terminal but the service keeps running, and this is what I want.

Anyway, if I run the script through the Gnome command "Run in terminal", when the terminal closes, also the service is killed.

That's very strange, I can't understand why and I'm not able to solve this problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing

```
nohup ./shell_script &
```

`nohup` command makes the process continue executing even after the terminal has closed, ignoring the `SIGHUP` signal.

Note the script will execute in the background, and the output will be appended to a file.

Comment: @l3golas  Also the above command , will output the Process ID of the executed shell script , hence you can monitor it once you login again.

Comment: Now I have just one more question: apparently the behavior of "Run in terminal" is different than the behavior of opening a terminal, executing the script and closing the terminal, since the first one while exiting kills the script (unless you use nohup), the second one instead doesn't kill it. Do you know why?

Comment: @l3golas I am not sure why you get a different behavior. My guess would be that either the shell script does something in the background, or that there is a bug in "Run in terminal".